# How to parse source code into english?

Tags: parsing, common-lisp

What step I have to take to build such program.

I want to have a program that take a simple (limited) java keyword into english human language.

e.g

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    int y;
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
 }

}
```

**to**

Declare HelloWorld Class
Declare main method
Declare variable x
Declare variable y
Print the word "Hello, World"
Close curly braces
Close curly braces

The program will read the source code line by line.

- I tried using `cl-ppcre`, but the problem is, I cant figure it out, how to take a word to temp.

  e.g

  Declare `HelloWord` then add "class" word.

  *not* `Declare class HelloWorld`, but I want `Declare Helloworld class`
- or, it's difficult to replace ");" at the end of print. Because another word have to be replaced.

I tried to read line by line

```
(with-open-file (input "~/test.java")
  (loop for line = (read-line input nil)
        while line do (format t "~a~%" (parse-laporan line))))
```

and parse it

```
(defun parse-laporan (isi)
  (cond
   ((cl-ppcre:scan "int " isi)
    (cl-ppcre:regex-replace "int" isi "Declare variable"))
   ((cl-ppcre:scan "System.out.print+" isi)
    (cl-ppcre:regex-replace   "System.out.print+" isi "print word "))
   ((cl-ppcre:scan "System.out.println+" isi)
    (cl-ppcre:regex-replace "System.out.println+" isi "print word "))
   ((cl-ppcre:scan "(" isi)
    (cl-ppcre:regex-replace "()" isi " "))
   ((cl-ppcre:scan "public class" isi)
    (cl-ppcre:regex-replace "public class" isi "Declare Kelas "))))
```

but it does not work well.

Do, I have to read all the content of the file and build an Abstract Syntax Tree ? (like an interpreter does)
or I can achieve it just by replacing word by word ?

Comment: very interesting project, [lintj](https://github.com/xach/linj) by António Menezes Leitão and it's [presentation slide](https://github.com/xach/linj/blob/master/doc/java-for-lispers.pdf)

Comment: What you do in your code has nothing to do with 'parsing'. All you do is to replace a text pattern with a string for each line.

Comment: Yes, that right. so that I don't give any "parse" name in my repo. I have to suspend this idea. It think I can achieve it by just replacing word here and there like what `awk` or `RegEx` does. But as [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726100/6000005) said, "Your problem is probably harder than what you imagine". I think it is right. So I will come back to this idea after finishing PCL and PAIP.

Answer (score 0):

> Do, I have to read all the content of the file and build an Abstract Syntax Tree ?

Of course yes.

And you probably want it to be not simply a *tree* but some [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

So you may want to keep *several* representations of your source code. You might want to have *several* passes.

PS. Your problem is probably harder than what you imagine. I would consider some [rule-based system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule-based_system) approach.